# That we’re a kind of Venn diagram come to life?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

Is this sentence - " that we’re a kind of Venn diagram **come to life**"- correct?

As I know, this is an object clause, and at here "**we**" is the subject and "**a kind of Venn diagram**" is the predicative. So the clause can be basically narrowed down to "we’re a kind of Venn diagram". Since "**come**" is a transitive verb and can't be regarded as a past participle here,  taking into account that "**come to life**" describes "Venn diagram", if it is more accurate to reframe the clause to "that we’re a kind of Venn diagram coming to life"?

---

> I think it’s time we move beyond the historical quest to find a single
>   theory of individuality to explain how the biological world is divided
>   up. What you are trying to grasp – be it development, physiology or
>   evolution – determines the interactions that will be important for
>   figuring out the boundaries of a creature. There isn’t one single
>   answer to the question of where to draw the limits of my body. We are
>   in constant interaction with the organisms living in and upon us – a
>   locus of biotic relations and overlapping borders. If you relax and
>   try to imagine every facet at once, you’ll see that we’re a kind of
>   Venn diagram **come to life**. I’m looking forward to the day I get to
>   share this with my daughter – perhaps the next time we go to the
>   aquarium to look at the coral, and she points and asks: ‘What’s that?’

source: [*AEON - Life is not easily bounded*](https://aeon.co/essays/what-constitutes-an-individual-organism-in-biology)

Comment: " _that we’re a kind of Venn diagram_ [which has] _come to life_" It's just a kind of contracted relative clause: _The people_ [who had been] _questioned were all released later._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minor clarification: that's a clause, not a sentence.  It wouldn't make sense on its own.  But yes, it is correct and idiomatic.

Yes, **come** is a past participle here.  [Participles, either present or past, can be used like adjectives](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm), for example:

> The cookies *baking* in the oven smell good.
>    The cookies *eaten* by my brother were intended for Aunt Sarah.

You can think of the participle as having an invisible "that is/are/were/was" or "that have/has":

> The cookies *(that are)* baking in the oven smell good.
>   The cookies *(that were)* eaten by my brother were intended for Aunt Sarah.

The sentence you're asking about is the same way:

> ...we're a kind of Venn diagram *(that has)* come to life.

If you used "coming to life", it would mean that we are a Venn diagram that is in the process of coming to life, not one that has already come to life.

To [come to life](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/come-to-life) is kind of an idiomatic phrase that means "to begin to work" or "to become lively and exciting" or simply "to change from a non-living thing to a living thing".  [It's much more common to see "come to life" than "coming to life".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come%20to%20life%2Ccoming%20to%20life&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20to%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoming%20to%20life%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I would classify this as an *idiom* or as an *ellipsis*.  The phrase "come to life" could be considered short for "That has come to life", but "come to life" itself is an idiomatic expression that means something inanimate has *become* animate or alive.

> As the blue fairy waved her wand, the puppet **came to life** and and became a real boy.

In this use, it's an adjective phrase modifying "a Venn diagram".  I agree it sounds a little awkward, but it doesn't need to be changed.